# Using active directory for application settings

Tags: .net, active-directory

Does Active Directory have support for application settings for the custom application I build?  How would I go about using Active Directory to allow my users to do settings rather then having a custom screen?

Comment: How do you currently configure your application?

Comment: Also, will the AD administrator be expected to know your application well in order to configure it, or do you have control of the AD environment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can manipulate Active Directory Schema, add new custom attribute to your AD object and use it for your own special needs :).

http://blogs.technet.com/b/isingh/archive/2007/02/18/adding-custom-attributes-in-active-directory.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Short answer, yes. You can use Active Directory to set registry values. You can also use it to launch scripts which will, for example, copy a configuration file into your application folder, or write out an INI file, or create an App.Config file.

The "ultimate" option is to write your own [ADM files](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Administrative_Template), which will allow the AD administrator to set your application settings using the normal GUI, rather than having to know a bunch of registry keys. This will make it very easy for the AD administrator to configure your application - all you will have to supply him with is documentation on the effect of the values.